# Как прикрутить проверку логина и пароля в телеграм бота на aiogram?

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

У меня есть телеграм бот на **aiogram**, который регистрирует пользователя - записывает его ник и пароль в базу данных. Всё работает.

Сюжет моего бота:

Пользователь пишет `/start`, бот просит ввести ник, затем пароль, и всё заносит в базу данных, после чего сообщает о завершении регистрации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее он выводит кнопку `ПРОФИЛЬ` и при нажатии на нее он должен просить ввести ник, затем **проверять правильность его введения**, и при **правильном введении** запрашивать пароль, и при правильном пароле сообщать об удачной авторизации

Но всеми стараниями я добился только того, что после введенного ника он больше ничего не отвечает. Сейчас уже убрал эту часть кода и теперь на введение слова ПРОФИЛЬ он ничего не делает `pass`. пытался оформить это через ifы, но результат всё тот же

Главный файл `bot.py`

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import markups as nav
from db import Database

TOKEN = "ТОКЕН"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

db = Database('database.db')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Укажите ваш ник")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы уже зарегистрированы!", reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)


@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'ПРОФИЛЬ':
           pass

        else:
            if db.get_signup(message.from_user.id) == 'setnickname':
                if(len(message.text) > 15):
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Никнейм не должен превышать 15 символов")
                else:
                    db.set_nickname(message.from_user.id, message.text)
                    db.set_signup(message.from_user.id, "setpassword")
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Придумайте пароль")

            else:
                if db.get_signup(message.from_user.id) == 'setpassword':
                    db.set_password(message.from_user.id, message.text)
                    db.set_signup(message.from_user.id, 'done')
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Регистрация заверена', reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Файл для работы с бд `db.py`:

```
import sqlite3

class Database():
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connect = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()

    def get_signup(self, user_id):
        result = self.connect.execute(f'SELECT signup FROM users WHERE user_id ={user_id}').fetchone()
        return result[0]

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connect:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        result = self.connect.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = {user_id}').fetchall()
        return bool(len(result))

    def set_nickname(self, user_id, nickname):
        with self.connect:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET nickname = ? WHERE user_id = ?", (nickname, user_id,))

    def set_signup(self, user_id, signup):
        with self.connect:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET signup = ? WHERE user_id = ?", (signup, user_id,))

    def set_password(self, user_id, password):
        with self.connect:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE user_id = ?", (password, user_id,))

    def get_nickname(self, user_id):
        result = self.connect.execute(f'SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE user_id ={user_id}').fetchone()
        return result[0]

    def get_password(self, user_id):
        result = self.connect.execute(f'SELECT password FROM users WHERE user_id ={user_id}').fetchone()
        return result[0]
```

Начал изучать aiogram. Помогите - как реализовать всё же эту проверку?

Comment: Точно так же как и в любом языке, вы хотите чтоб сделали за вас или помогли разобраться? если второе - уточните более конкретно в чем у вас проблема

Comment: Уточню мое негодование - в вашем коде написано ровно это: при сообщении ПРОФИЛЬ в приватном чате - не делать ничего

Comment: Да, я хочу разобраться как это собственно реализовать на python и aiogram.

Мне нужно, чтобы бот выполнял такой "линейный диалог". 

Пользователь должен нажать на кнопку "ПРОФИЛЬ", затем бот должен спрашивать поочередно логин и пароль, которые уже есть в БД. 

То есть только после нажатия на ПРОФИЛЬ, он будет принимать ник, проверять его, и только после правильности - запрашивать пароль и проверять его.

Как мне реализовать такую цепочку проверки с этой библиотекой, чтобы он только после кнопки "ПРОФИЛЬ" "запускал" её?

Comment: Если оформить всё отдельно, то при введении, например, ника, в середине диалога - он будет запрашивать пароль. Но мне нужно только при условии, что пользователь сам запустил этот процесс авторизации.

Я пытался прописать @dp.message_handler(text=['ПРОФИЛЬ']) и уже в нем это писать, но тогда он будет реагировать только на сообщение "профиль", а на ник и пароль - нет

Comment: Понял в чем ваша проблема, вы не первый, вот к изучению: https://habr.com/ru/post/358304/, если этот материал будет слишком сложным - поищите в поисковиках "машина состояний"

Comment: Очень благодарен! Изучу этот материал

Comment: Ну я к тому что это именно то что вам нужно реализовать чтобы получить то что вы хотите :)

Comment: [**Практическое программирование Python**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOWaWydDLr2unk_F0LcvT1w/playlists) \
Я учился у него, смотри плейлист *Telegram Bot* (aiogram)
Там 36 или 37 урок - начало про то что тебе нужно FSM

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так. Вход в профиль по аналогии

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
# делаем сторедж (обязательно)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


# делаем стейты, каждый стейт будет как фильтр, при котором будет срабатывать хендлер
class RegisterFSM(StatesGroup):
    nickname_input = State()
    pass_input = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    # не стоит делать скобки просто так в условиях
    if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
        # юзать такой тип немного опасно так как может прокнуть ошибка
        # что юзер написал это сообщениею боту в какой-нибудь группе
        # а вы пытаетесь написать в лс
        # раз уж вы как разумный человек юзаете aiogram
        # просто делайте вместо
        # await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Укажите ваш ник")
        # так
        await message.answer("Укажите ваш ник")
        # ну и тут нам нужно запустить стейт
        await RegisterFSM.nickname_input.set()
    else:
        await message.answer("Вы уже зарегистрированы!", reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)


# забываем про пустые хендлеры
# @dp.message_handler()
# делаем всегда (почти с фильтрами)
# d нашем случае ставим фильтр стейт
@dp.message_handler(state=RegisterFSM.nickname_input)
async def input_nick(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # проверка на длину
    if len(message.text) > 15:
        await message.answer("Никнейм не должен превышать 15 символов")
        return
        # если всё ок то записываем в стейт дату (внутренне хранилище aiogram)
    # работает как словарь
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['nick'] = message.text
    # теперь требуем пароль, для этого меняем стейт
    # так как мы их обявляли по порядку можно юзать функцию next
    await RegisterFSM.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=RegisterFSM.pass_input)
async def input_pass(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # тут записываете эти данные в бд
    ...
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        db.set_nickname(message.from_user.id, data['nick'])
        db.set_password(message.from_user.id, message.text)

    await message.answer('Регистрация заверена', reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)
    # ну и по окончаню сбрасываем стейт и всё данные в дате
    await state.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```